# Confused about encrypting in browser and decrypting on server

Tags: encryption, cryptojs, webcrypto-api

Here's something I don't understand.

I've played with some code examples on how to encrypt a string in the *browser* and decrypt the ciphered text on the *server* and I don't see how this is secure at all.

All of the examples assume that the same `iv` and the `key` used to encrypt the string will be sent to the server so it knows how to decrypt it.

Isn't that like taping the keys to the safe?

Am I supposed to send the `iv` and `key` object with the payload, along with the encrypted string?

I have to be missing something here.

```
async function generateKey() {

  return await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey({
            name:   "AES-CBC",
            length: 256
          },
          false,
          ["encrypt", "decrypt"]);

}

async function encryptString(data, key, iv) {

   return await window.crypto.subtle.encrypt(
          {
            name: "AES-CBC",
            iv,
          },
          key,
          data
        );

}

async function decryptString(data, key, iv) {

        const decrypted = await window.crypto.subtle.decrypt(
          {
            name: "AES-CBC",
            iv,
          },
          key,
          data
        );

        return new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(new Uint8Array(decrypted));

}

async function example() {

     try {

       // Create the IV and Key
       const iv = window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(16));
       const key = await generateKey();

       // Convert the string I want to encrypt into an ArrayBuffer
       const data = new TextEncoder("utf-8").encode('Hello World!');
     
       // Encrypt the ArrayBuffer
       const ciphertext = await encryptString(data, key, iv);
       console.log(ciphertext);

       // Now I decrypt the obscured string using the same key and iv I used to encrypt it.
       const decrypted = await decryptString(ciphertext, key, iv);

       // Hello World!
       console.log(decrypted);

     } catch(error) {

       console.log(error);

     }

}
```

Comment: The IV is not a secret, the key most definitely is. You must have some way of securely getting the key to both parties. That's a hard problem in general. Public key cryptography solves part of the problem, but still requires establishing trust of public keys. Hard-coding trusted certificate authority (CA) public keys is the most common way of doing this. The internet HTTPS ecosystem of browsers, servers, and CAs is engineered to address all these issues (thought not perfectly of course) and it's best to rely on them unless you have significant expertise in this area.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the Symmetric Key between browser and server must be established using Asymmetric key first.

Like HTTS (TLS or SSL) is encrypted channel using Asymmetric key (Public key at Browser and Private key at server).

Thus you may rely on Encrypted Channel using HTTPS (TLS) to protect your Symmetric keys or alternatively, you may develop your own mechanism to protect it using Asymmetric keys, for which you will have to generate pair of keys (common for all users - at server or for every user), publish public key to clients and clients will use that public key to encrypt Symmetric key (and iv) which you will decrypt using server side private key.  Once Asymmetric key is established, you can use it for fixed duration as per security requirements and then repeat the process, say after every 1 hour or 6 hours or 24 hours, etc.

Comment: Thank you. Your explanation helped.  But what about encryption that uses an IV? The IV has to be shared between client and server and the IV is supposed to be re-generated with each encryption so, to make this handshake between client and server work, don't you have to attach they key to the payload?  The same key that will unlock the data?